# Very weird behavior when using "var" keyword in an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, var

I've been worrying about this for a while and I can't realize what's really happening. Explanation in code comments. There are 2 versions of an application, one of them throws weird results and the second one does the expected work.

```
var id = "test1";

$.post("http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/", {"data": "data"}, function(a) {
     alert(id); // will throw undefined

     var id = "test2";
     alert(id); // will throw "test2" as expected
});
```

---

```
$.post("http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/", {"data": "data"}, function(a) {
    alert(id); // will throw "test1" as expected

    id = "test2";
    alert(id); // will throw "test2" as expected
});
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with ajax call, or an anonymous function, but this is just the way I discovered this so I better keep it there. Could somebody explain what am I missing? Why does it behave differently when I ommit the `var` keyword? You can try everything out [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4qe5jyv/3/)

Comment: I don't feel this is an exact duplicate as it's question asked in time I haven't any idea of hoisting. This is more of a question which ask "what is it", not "how it behaves". Voting to reopen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cool, you discovered `hoisting`. MDN explains it as good as anyone:

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

Code sample from MDN link below:

```
bla = 2
var bla;
// ...

// is implicitly understood as:

var bla;
bla = 2;
```

You can see how this will result in the "weird behaviour":

```
alert(testId);
var testId = 2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var testId;
alert(testId);
testId = 2;
```

Which brings me to the final bit of knowledge I can impart, **always** declare your variables at the top of your code blocks so this "weird behaviour" is coded into your programs (and never throws you off again):

```
function someFunction() {
   var
    firstVar,
    secondVar,
    thirdVar;

    //rest of your code statements here
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: wow, I've just learnt really interesting thing! I bet I'll keep this in mind, thanks

Comment: Just another question, does this mean that any line which isn't even ever executed (inside a function) can break the whole code? Based on your last edit, it makes me think it does "hoist" only before executing the function. Am I right?

Comment: @Martin. absolutely. `var ten = 10; (function() { if(false) { var ten = false; } alert(ten); /* alerts undefined, at first glance, you'd expect it to alert 10 */ }());`

Comment: damn, this is the weirdest behavior I've seen in JS

Comment: Thank you everyone who've helped me for your assistence and I'm really sorry I can't accept all the answers. Big up for the SO community once again!

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, it's hoisting. But just so you can have a clearer view of what is happening, the first code is actually executed like this:

```
var id = "test1";

$.post("http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/", {"data": "data"}, function(a) {
     // this is because of hoisting
     var id = undefined;
     alert(id); // will throw undefined

     id = "test2";
     alert(id); // will throw "test2" as expected
});
```

Comment: Well, I think I'm not quite sure why is this happening. It goes through the code, initialize the variable "id" without filling in any value (thus clearing value from the first line) and fills its value to "test2" after the first alert?

Comment: @Martin. Exactly as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Its called hoisting. `var id` is moved to the top of the function.

Comment: Without filling the value?

Comment: @Martin - correct. It declares the variable before any other code statements so it's not undefined, then assigns it the value on the original line of code.